# Prove by Induction $4\times (1+5+5^2+...+5^n) + 1 = 5^{n+1}$

Tags: induction

I can't prove this using the induction method. Can anyone help me?

$$4\times (1+5+5^2+...+5^n) + 1 = 5^{n+1}$$

Comment: What have have you tried?

Comment: Have you verified the base case ? Have you identified your inductive hypothesis ? Please edit these into your question ... so we know where you need some help.

Comment: I have thought of three ways of doing this. What is your base case, and what is your induction step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$4\cdot (1+5+5^2+\dots+5^n+5^{n+1}) + 1 = [4\cdot (1+5+5^2+\dots+5^n) + 1]+4\cdot 5^{n+1}$$

Comment: Thank you! I have solved it using your hint! :D

Comment: @Numox Fine. BTW if you are new here take a few second for a tour https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

This seems like homework, so here's a hint:

Prove by induction that $1+5+5^2+...+5^n=\frac{1-5^{n+1}}{1-5}$

From there, the following is rather easy.

Comment: For further reference, what you're begin asked to calculate is the sequence of a **geometric series**.